# Sum All Records Queried from COALESCE mySQL

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I have a command (below) that works well and returns about 23 records. It grabs int data of like records from another table, and sums each records up for me. Now I want to take it a step further and reduce these 23 records into 1, where it will give me the sum of all 23 records. Is this possible?

```
SELECT COALESCE(SUM(d.Seconds),0)+a.Seconds AS Seconds
FROM table_One AS a
LEFT JOIN table_Two AS d ON d.ForeignKey = a.ID
GROUP BY a.ID
```

I would like to do something like:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(SUM(d.Seconds),0)+a.Seconds) AS Seconds
```

But that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need two `SUM`

```
   select sum(coalesce(d.Seconds, 0) + a.seconds) as seconds
    from table_One a
    LEFT JOIN table_Two d on d.ForeignKey = a.Id
```

Comment: I didn't drop the group by at first. Thank you!